# How to get value from an input and pass it to a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I'm in the process of making little point-and-click game using html5 and jQuery. Even though I'm complete noob at these, up until now I didn't have any significant problems. But recently I've encountered problem I can't seem to tackle - I've tried to search answers online, but even when they seemed relevant, I couldn't fix it anyway. So here is the thing: 
I'd like to make input where player could write answer to the riddle (and preferably submit it by pressing enter, but now I have button for testing purposes, as onclick seemed to me to be easier way to do it) and the answer would go to the function that would determine what dialogue would show next. But somehow whatever I do the input doesn't seem go into this function. Probably it's very basic error, but I can't spot it. 
Here's code:

```
<div id="answera" data-actor="francois">
        <input type="text" id='answer1'/>
        <input type="button" value="Test" onclick="testRiddle('answer1', '2')" />
</div>
```

testRiddle function:

```
testRiddle: function(myfield, answer) {
    var myData = document.getElementById("#location_partI1 ."+myfield).value;
    if(myData!==''){
        if(myData == answer){
            game.dialogue.show($("#location_partI1 .answer1right"));

        }else{
            game.dialogue.show($("#location_partI1 .answer1wrong"));

        }
    }else{
        game.dialogue.show($("#location_partI1 .lackofinput"));

    }

},
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you have jQuery loaded you can get the input value using `$('#answer1').val();`

Comment: Shouldn't `("#location_partI1 ."+myfield)` be `("#answera #"+myfield)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need:

```
testRiddle: function(myfield, answer) {
    var myData = document.getElementById(myfield).value;
    if(myData!==''){
        if(myData == answer){
            game.dialogue.show($("#location_partI1 .answer1right"));//is answer1right a class or id???

        }else{
            game.dialogue.show($("#location_partI1 .answer1wrong"));//same here???

        }
    }else{
        game.dialogue.show($("#location_partI1 .lackofinput"));//still the same here???

    }

},
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
var myData = document.getElementById("#location_partI1 ."+myfield).value;
```

should be this:

```
var myData = $("#location_partI1 ."+myfield).val();
```

Comment: Ensure that your selector is actually pointing at the correct input tag. It should have a class equal to what ever myfield is and be a child of an object with id="location_partI1"